# Fantasy novel where girl enters the world of fairy tales

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a fantasy novel which I read 3 years ago. I want to read it again, but the problem is I don't remember much about the novel. It was about a girl who gets letters from her grandfather (maybe?) and somehow enters into the world of stories or maybe turns into a fictional character, as if she was reading about herself in some story book. She is able to see the fictional characters (eg. Snow white, dwarfs, Cinderella) and normal people can't see her anymore.

Comment: Can you remember any more details that might help identify the novel. Such as: What language was it written in? Where is it set? Is it set in the past, present or future?

Comment: @Valorum that title is actually wrong, if I have the story right.

Comment: @Mithrandir - Yes, but it matches the question. We don't retrospectively change Story-ID titles to match correct answers

Answer (score 10):

*[Sophie's World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie%27s_World)*,  by Jostein Gaarder.

In this book Sophie is reading something that she's receiving in the mail. It contains messages to someone with Care of Sophie. At the end,  it turns out that she is a character in a book and then she escapes with her teacher from the book.  She meets the fantasy characters and the regular people can't see her anymore.

From Wikipedia:

> Sophie Amundsen (Sofie Amundsen in the
> Norwegian version) is a 14-year-old girl who lives in Norway in the
> year 1990.
>       The book begins with Sophie
> receiving two messages in her mailbox and a postcard addressed to
> Hilde Møller Knag. Afterwards, she receives a packet of papers, part
> of a course in philosophy.
>       Sophie,
> without the knowledge of her mother, becomes the student of an old
> philosopher, Alberto Knox. Alberto teaches her about the history of
> philosophy. She gets a substantive and understandable review from the
> Pre-Socratics to Jean-Paul Sartre. Along with the philosophy lessons,
> Sophie and Alberto try to outwit the mysterious Albert Knag, who
> appears to have God-like powers, which Alberto finds quite
> troubling.
>       Sophie and Alberto's entire
> world is revealed to be a literary construction by Albert Knag as a
> present for his daughter, Hilde, on her 15th birthday.
>      As Albert Knag continues to meddle with
> Sophie's life, Alberto helps her fight back by teaching her everything
> he knows about philosophy. Alberto manages to find a plan so that he
> and Sophie can finally escape Albert's imagination. The "trick" is
> performed on Midsummer's Eve, after Alberto informs Sophie's mother
> about everything.

When Sophie receives the letter for Hilde:

> Sophie felt her pulse quicken a little as she saw who the postcard was addressed to: "Hilde Møller Knag, c/o Sophie Amundsen, 3 Clover Close..."
>
> Dear Hilde, Happy 15th birthday! As I'm sure you'll understand, I want to give you a present that will help you grow. Forgive me for sending the card c/o Sophie. It was the easiest way. Love from Dad.

When Hilde reads this part:

> Hilde read on and on. With surprise, she reads about Sophie Amundsen receiving a postcard from Lebanon. "Hilde Møller Knag, c/o Sophie Amundsen, 3 Clover Close..." (above text)

Meeting fantasy characters:

> "I'm out of one of Grimm's Fairy Tales. That was nearly two hundred years ago. And where are you from?"
> "We're out of a book on philosophy. I am the philosophy teacher and this is my student, Sophie."

Comment: By the description in a question, I doubt that Sophie's world is a correct answer. Of course, the informations match. But I read it and the last thing I would remember is that Sophie is meeting fantasy (or even fairy tail) characters. The whole book is actually about philosophy and that is very clear from it. It seems very strange to me that OP would remember the fairy tails characters and not the philosophy.